# How to extract SSID from result of 'netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'interface' in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find my SSID using Python and netsh. So far I've got this, which works:

```
x = subprocess.run (['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'interface'],
                         capture_output=True, text=True)
print(x.stdout)
```

But now I'd like to capture the SSID and maybe others in variables to use later and I can't figure out how to do that in Python. It seems like there should be a simple command to get just one of all the details in stdout but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: You'll have to parse the output from the command to get what you want. I'm not on a Windows machine so I don't know what the `netsh` output looks like these days, but it's probably going to be a number of lines with a single piece of information on each.

Comment: Yes, that's what it looks like.  And that's what I was afraid of.  I can probably find it easily enough, but was hoping there was a more direct way